# Uploading MP3 audio books to new android.

Tags: applications

Have audio books in MP3. Want to upload them to my new android. What software do I need on each device (PC & Android)?

Answer (score 1):

None. Just connect your phone to your computer with USB and make sure the phone is set to MTP mode. You can do it from there.

If you want to do it OTA I can personally suggest [Web PC Suite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.wps&hl=tr) application